# Define abstract environment in book

Tags: document-classes, preamble, abstract

I want to define an abstract environment for `\documentclass{book}`. Therefore, I copied the relevant definitions from `report.cls` from [here](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/missing-files/report.cls) into my preamble. But it doesn't work. Where's the problem?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{This and That}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I know there are lot's of solutions on the web on how to write abstracts in the book class. I am mainly interested in the question why my solution of defining the environment technically doesn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using `\abstractname` in the environment, but latex does not know it. This is the error you got. Hence defining it solves the issue. You have to define `\abstractname` by

```
\newcommand\abstractname{Abstract}
```

Your MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\abstractname{Abstract}  %%% here
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{This and That}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a short explanation why this is necessary?

Comment: @lpdbw: You are using `\abstractname` in the environment, but latex does not know it. This is the error you got. Hence defining it solves the issue.

Comment: You could just have used the `memoir` class instead, it is `book`-like and provide an abstract environment

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Harish! Unfortunately, as the title page, abstract and the ToC appear only on odd-numbered pages when using the book document class, there are two blank pages surrounding the abstract. This would be no problem if they didn't carry *the same page number* (namely 2 instead of 2 and 4). Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: @balu: Use `openany` in the option for `book` → `\documentclass[openany]{book}`

Answer (score 3):

```
\newenvironment{abstract}[1]{%
\begin{center}\normalfont\textbf{Abstract}\end{center}
\begin{quotation} #1 \end{quotation}
}{%
\vspace{1cm}
}
```

works for me reasonably well. Simply call with `\abstract{}`.

[image: screen shot of example output]

Comment: Please as usual here make your given code snippet compilable for a fast proof. Can you please also add your result as screenshot to your answer?