# How to insert mutliple abstracts on one page in a book LaTeX document?

Tags: abstract

I know `abstract` usually is not defined for book classes, but [you can define it by yourself as a workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539606/98645).
However, it seems to always force itself on a new page, i.e. it forces a single page for an abstract.
This is bad, if I e.g. want to add multiple abstracts for different languages (e.g. one for the language the paper is written in and one in English).

Here is the simplified code:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,numbers=noenddot,oneside]{scrbook}

% deutsch
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage{lmodern} % font
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes} % deutsche Anführungszeichen mit \enquote

% abstract in book, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539606/98645
\newenvironment{abstract}{}{}
\usepackage{abstract}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \setstretch{1.0}
    \hypersetup{hidelinks}
    \tableofcontents
    \endgroup
    
    \pagebreak

%   \vfill
    
    \begin{abstract}
        Dies ist ein schöner Beispieltext für einen Abstract für ein Paper darüber, wie Abstracts ohne allzu viel Abstraktion abstrahiert werden können.
    \end{abstract}
    
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \begin{abstract}
        This is a nice example text for an abstract for a paper about how abstracts can be abstracted without too much abstraction.
    \end{abstract}
    \selectlanguage{ngerman}

    % […]
\end{document]
```

This way, it forces **a new page** for **each** abstract.
I have experimented with [redefining the abstract beginning and end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/963070), but by using the code there and adding some `\vfill`'s I could get it one one page, but then it was not vertically centered anymore.
I have also tested `onecolabstract` instead of the `abstract` env, but it did not make a difference.
The [abstract package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/abstract) also does not seem to provide any helpful options here, according to it's doc.

And yes [I have seen this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164700/98645), but it is about a document with a `report` style, where apparently the abstract is never put on a single page, respectively the `abstract` package does not force a page break. As such, the answers there just circle around how to put the title on the same page etc.

And BTW, no, switching to [another LaTeX style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/758059) is not solution – I want the book style for other reasons, obviously.

Basically my aim can be summarized like this:
I want to put **two abstracts one one page** and have them nicely centered just like when you only have one abstract one one page.

Comment: Vertical centering requires balancing the `\vfill`s before and after, and possibly throwing in a `\null` at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an abridged version of `abstract` from `scrartcl`:

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,numbers=noenddot,oneside]{scrbook}

% deutsch
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage{lmodern} % font
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes} % deutsche Anführungszeichen mit \enquote

\makeatletter
\newif\if@abstractlanguage
\newenvironment{abstract}[1][]
 {%
  \par\addvspace{3\baselineskip} % adjust to suit
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \else\@abstractlanguagetrue
    \begin{otherlanguage}{#1}%
  \fi
  \begin{center}
  \normalfont\sectfont
  \nobreak\abstractname\@endparpenalty\@M\end{center}
  \begin{quotation}
 }
 {%
  \end{quotation}%
  \if@abstractlanguage\end{otherlanguage}\fi
 }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Dies ist ein schöner Beispieltext für einen Abstract für ein Paper darüber, 
wie Abstracts ohne allzu viel Abstraktion abstrahiert werden können.
\end{abstract}
    
\begin{abstract}[english]
This is a nice example text for an abstract for a paper about how abstracts 
can be abstracted without too much abstraction.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to center them in the page, you can define a wrapper environment:

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,numbers=noenddot,oneside]{scrbook}

% deutsch
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage{lmodern} % font
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes} % deutsche Anführungszeichen mit \enquote

\makeatletter
\newif\if@abstractlanguage
\newenvironment{abstracts}{\cleardoublepage\vspace*{\fill}}{\vspace*{\fill}}
\newenvironment{abstract}[1][]
 {%
  \par\addvspace{3\baselineskip} % adjust to suit
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \else\@abstractlanguagetrue
    \begin{otherlanguage}{#1}%
  \fi
  \begin{center}
  \normalfont\sectfont
  \nobreak\abstractname\@endparpenalty\@M\end{center}
  \begin{quotation}
 }
 {%
  \end{quotation}%
  \if@abstractlanguage\end{otherlanguage}\fi
 }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{abstracts}

\begin{abstract}
Dies ist ein schöner Beispieltext für einen Abstract für ein Paper darüber, 
wie Abstracts ohne allzu viel Abstraktion abstrahiert werden können.
\end{abstract}
    
\begin{abstract}[english]
This is a nice example text for an abstract for a paper about how abstracts 
can be abstracted without too much abstraction.
\end{abstract}

\end{abstracts}

\end{document}
```

[image]