# Why "environment abstract undefined" after usepackage{abstract)

Tags: luatex

How to have a title with `scrbook`?

I have added `usepackage{abstract}` but receive the error `environment abstract undefined`.

I try to compile with LuaHBTeX 1.12.0 the following reduced example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,notitlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\title{01blog1 titel Mein erster Blog}
\author{AUF}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}01blog1 abstract Ein Blog ohne Sinn auf Deutsch\end{abstract}
    
    \section{01blog1 level1 Ein erster Abschnitt} 
    
    Ein Blog ohne Sinn und dem einzigen Zweck, zu testen, wie ein Blog in
    ein PDF umgewandelt wird.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Book-type document classes usually don't feature an abstract.

Comment: This is why I think I have to add the 'usepackage{abstract}.

Comment: You are using `scrbook` which is *very* different from `scrartcl`. For instance, you should start with a `\chapter` before using `\section`. Just use `\chapter{Abstract}` after `\frontmatter` and before `\mainmatter`.

Answer (score 1):

Perusing   [other answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100729) I found the suggestion for a solution with

```
\newenvironment{abstract}{}{}
\usepackage{abstract}
```

i.e. the environment must be defined first.

Not very obvious, but problem solved.

Comment: Your link doesn't work.  And I'm suspicious that the ordering of those would matter (assuming it solve the problem).