# Summary for parts of one book

Tags: book-design, abstract

I would like to write little summaries at the begining of each part of one book.

How do you do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the first glance, I was wondering: why is this guy not using the abstract environment? Ah, it does not exist in the documentclass book. Hm.

There are several solutions:

1. Define abstract for books. Fortunately somebody has done that for us: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68227/4736
2. Use another documentclass, I read that memoir allegedly offers abstracts for all classes.
3. Just use something like `\section*{Abstract}`

However, some more details on your wishes would help us to give further advice.