# How can I vertically center a predefined abstract environment to the middle of text body?

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, geometry, abstract, front-matter

I got a low level TeX code from [Define abstract environment in book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68222/define-abstract-environment-in-book/68227#68227) that defines an environment for Abstract. However, when I put it in my work, I use `notitlepage` option which results in the abstract being aligned vertically to the top. As shown here, the abstract text does not justify to the available width; there is an empty space to the left and to the right.

Right now I want the whole abstract (both title and text) to align vertically to the center of the text body and fully justify the text to save as much as possible of space.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\frontmatter}{\pagenumbering{roman}}{\pagenumbering{Roman}}{}{}

% ===== Define abstract environment =====
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
    \titlepage
    \null\vfil
    \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
    \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
\end{center}}%
{\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
    \if@twocolumn
    \section*{\abstractname}%
    \else
    \small
    \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
    \fi}
{\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother


\begin{document}




\frontmatter

\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents


\pagestyle{headings}

\cleardoublepage
\begin{abstract}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\abstractname}


\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables


\mainmatter

\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument


\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never just copy/paste code. You need to understand it first.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{book}
%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\frontmatter}{\pagenumbering{roman}}{\pagenumbering{Roman}}{}{}

% ===== Define abstract environment =====
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
    \clearpage
\vspace*{\fill}
    \small
    \begin{center}%
    {\bfseries Abstract}
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
\end{center}%
}
{\vspace*{\fill}
}


\begin{document}




\frontmatter

\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents


\pagestyle{headings}

\cleardoublepage
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}


\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables


\mainmatter

\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument


\end{document}
```

[image: almotasemAbstract]